# Eclipse J-Face Wizard: How to create next page dynamically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface, wizard

I have an eclipse JFace wizard with a single page (let's call this `page1`) which is added to the `mainWizard` using `addPage(page1)`.

I wish to have a second page (`page2`), but this can only be created from a value determined from `page1` (and so cannot be added to the `mainWizard`)

Is there a way I can add this from `page1` to be create when I push its **next** button?

EDIT:
Currently I have created the new page in `page1`, and then overridden `getNextPage()` as follows

```
@Override
public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
 if (page2 != null) {
  return page2;
 }
 System.err.println("page not populated");
 return null;
}
```

and although I don't get the "page not populated" message, when I press next I'm hit with a `NullPointerException` on `WizardDialog.setWizard`.

Comment: when you say it cant be created without knowing some value of page one you refer to the components you want to use or the data to populate them? could you use something like the plane and car example in http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JFaceWizards/index.html?

Comment: Not in this case, as the page2 wizard (which I cannot edit) could only be instantiated with the value I need to select from page1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical approach when writing a JFace wizard is to extend `Wizard` class and add pages in the `addPages()` method. While that's convenient for many cases, you can choose to implement `IWizard` interface directly and have all the control you need over the creation and sequencing of pages.

Comment: Thank you, I created page2 in page1 and then called page2.setWizard(this) in my main Wizard class when I knew I could create it.

Answer (score 6):

The `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard` has all that is needed to add pages dynamically *at the end* of the existing steps. You can do so by overriding `getNextPage` to return a new page if conditions are met:

```
@Override
public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
   IWizardPage nextPage = super.getNextPage(page);
   if (nextPage == null) {
      if (userInputRequiresMorePage){
         // The user input is such that we need an additional page to append to the wizard.
         IWizardPage nextPage = new MyAdditionalPage();
      }
   }
   return nextPage;
}
```

If your wizard start with only one page, "back" and "next" buttons do not appear by default. As you may need more steps, you want to display them. You can do so by setting the proper flag using the API

```
public void org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.setForcePreviousAndNextButtons(boolean b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second page which just has a composite and call `addPage` for that in the wizard `addPages`.

In the second page override the `setVisible(boolean)` method and create the controls you need when the page becomes visible.